# How do I select a random item from a weighted array in Julia?

Tags: arrays, julia, random

Consider two 1-dim arrays, one with items to select from and one containing the probabilities of drawing the item of the other list.

```
items = ["a", 2, 5, "h", "hello", 3]
weights = [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3]
```

**In Julia, how can one randomly select an item in `items` using `weights` to weight the probability to drawing a given item?**

Comment: @Prix Thanks for you update. Isn't it important to indicate the language of interest in the title for such question? Maybe in parenthesis at the end of the question?

Comment: Ok, thanks. Indeed, it would be great to be able to order the tags.

Comment: Hope you like it this way, I see no reason not to have it there either so I guess it comes down to personal preferences ;)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use the `StatsBase.jl` package, i.e.

```
Pkg.add("StatsBase")  # Only do this once, obviously
using StatsBase
items = ["a", 2, 5, "h", "hello", 3]
weights = [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3]
sample(items, Weights(weights))
```

Or if you want to sample many:

```
# With replacement
my_samps = sample(items, Weights(weights), 10)
# Without replacement
my_samps = sample(items, Weights(weights), 2, replace=false)
```

(In Julia < 1.0, `Weights` was called `WeightVec`).

You can learn more about `Weights` and why it exists [in the docs](http://juliastats.github.io/StatsBase.jl/stable/weights/). The sampling algorithms in `StatsBase` are very efficient and designed to use different approaches depending on the size of the input.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a much simpler approach which only uses Julia's base library:

```
sample(items, weights) = items[findfirst(cumsum(weights) .> rand())]
```

Example:

```
>>> sample(["a", 2, 5, "h", "hello", 3], [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3])
"h"
```

This is less efficient than `StatsBase.jl`, but for small vectors it's fine.

Also, if `weights` is not a normalized vector, you can do:

```
sample(items, weights) = items[findfirst(cumsum(weights) .> rand() * sum(weights))]
```

Comment: Can I use this to generate multiple elements from a list (without replacement)?