# How to select n unique elements at random, from a list of elements in Julia

Tags: random, julia

I want to generate n unique elements from a list of numbers. I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67812522/11607243) answer but that only gives me one element. I want n distinct elements from the list.

How do I go about doing this?

I have tried using `rand(list,n)` but this sometimes gives me repeated elements from `list` so that doesn't work.

Comment: Is the list small and in memory? If yes, you can shuffle it and take a prefix of length `n`.

Comment: Sometimes it is a list of numbers of variable length. Other times, it is a column of numbers from a `DataFrame`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try <s>`Distributions.sample`</s> `StatsBase.sample`:

```
jl> using StatsBase: sample

jl> x = rand(10);

jl> sample(x, 3; replace=false)
3-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.6816165016249632
 0.8500982926818003
 0.6518188633423712
```

Comment: It looks like Distributions is just [reexporting sample from StatsBase](https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distributions.jl/blob/fb9ce8a1a3a3c860128c62bba8336140fe7dbef8/src/Distributions.jl#L262), but is there some benefit to using it via `Distributions` instead of directly using `StatsBase`?

Comment: I don't think so. I just cast about to see where `sample` was located, didn't find it in Statistics, so thought of Distributions.jl. I though Statistics depended on StasBase, so it never occurred to me to look there.